# Decide if it true for non-negative random variables $Var(\min(X,Y))... \min(Var(X), Var(Y))$

Tags: probability

There are two **non-negative** random variables $X,Y$.  Decide what relation is between following expressions:
$Var(\min(X,Y))... \min(Var(X), Var(Y))$

It seems to be hard for me,  The only thing that I can show is:
$E(\min(X,Y))\le \min(E(X,Y))$.
Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Below is an example.

---

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$. Concretely,
$$
\Pr[X = 1] = p; \quad \Pr[X = 0] = 1-p
$$
Then $Z = \min\{X, Y\}$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p^2$. That is,
$$
\Pr[Z = 1] = p^2; \quad \Pr[Z = 0] = 1 -p^2
$$
We thus have
$$
Var[Z] = p^2 - p^4 \tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$
and
$$
Var[X] = Var[Y] = p-p^2 \tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$

---

- When $p = \frac{1}{2}$, we have
  $$\min\{Var[X], Var[Y]\} = Var[X] = \frac{1}{4}$$
  and
  $$
  Var[\min\{X, Y\}] = Var[Z] = \frac{3}{16}
  $$
  The term $\min\{Var[X], Var[Y]\}$ is greater.
- When $p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we have
  $$\min\{Var[X], Var[Y]\} = Var[X] = \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} < \frac{1}{4}$$
  and
  $$
  Var[\min\{X, Y\}] = Var[Z] = \frac{1}{4}
  $$
  The term $Var[\min\{X, Y\}]$ is greater.

Comment: Thanks you very much! Your solution is very clear :)  When it comes to $E(\min(X,Y))\le \min(E(X,Y))$ - It seems to me that I managed to prove it. However, tell me one thing: this inequality is true  ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Because $\min\{X, Y\} \leq X$ and $\min\{X, Y\} \leq Y$, we have $E[\min\{X, Y\}] \leq E[X]$ and $E[\min\{X, Y\}] \leq E[Y]$. Therefore, $E[\min\{X, Y\}] \leq \min\{E[X], E[Y]\}$.